# video.js .src() function not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

here is part of my code:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
        if (content=="play()") {
                $('title').html("screen:"+content);
            myPlayer.play();
        }
        if (content=="pause()") {
                $('title').html("screen:"+content);
            myPlayer.pause();
        }
        if (content.indexOf("src(")!=-1) {
            var videoMP4 = content.replace("src(","").replace(")","");
            myPlayer.src({type: "video/mp4", src:videoMP4});
            // {type: "video/webm", src:videoMP4.replace(".mp4", ".webm")},
            //  {type: "video/ogg", src:videoMP4.replace(".mp4", ".ogv")}
            // ]
            myPlayer.play();
        }
```

the pause function and the play function work as expected. But for some reason when the code reaches the

```
myPlayer.src({type: "video/mp4", src:videoMP4});
```

i get an error in my console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'src' of object #<HTMLVideoElement> is not a function
```

any idea why this happens?

Comment: myPlayer.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4" });
this is the example from the documentation site

Answer (score 7):

`var myPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");`

returns a standard HTML `video` element. You need to use:

`var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");`

to get the VideoJS object.

Comment: i tried that but i am gettting: ReferenceError: _V_ is not defined 
i am defining the video element in another file.. (i am sending script/html files from the server and adding them on the dom tree)

Comment: Are you including the Video.JS library before you are trying to execute your code?

Comment: nope. what i am doing is i start of with an empty page, and sending html/script blocks from the server. the first thing i am sending is the video.. and the manually i request the change of the video, so i don't think it's a timing issue.. but the change of src request is in a different code block that is sent from the server

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of what your complete code looks like (use jsfiddle.net if possible)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GjUBV/ this is the empty page i create at first;
the startEddie() function starts a process that initiates a connection with the server, and receives parts blocks to append to the page. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qTzE4/ this is the html/script part that i append to the empty screen.
then at some point a request comes in that triggers the part i posted above that doesn't work

Comment: Can you include the eddie.js file in your example (add it as a resource on the side bar), I'm not seeing where your code above fits into this example.

Answer (score 2):

Change the source and type like:

```
myPlayer.setAttribute("src", videoMP4);
myPlayer.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
myPlayer.load();  # Force video refresh...
```

Comment: this works! thanks! but how can i add 3 src attributes this way for 3 different file types? this way it won't work in all browsers..

Comment: This works because it's manipulating the video element through the standard DOM API, it doesn't involve the Video.JS library at all. The Video.JS library provides a way to fall back to different types the standard DOM API doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

src is a "DOMString", not a function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

> Reflects the src HTML attribute, containing the URL of a media resource to use.
>   Gecko implements a similar functionality is available for streams: mozSrcObject.

myPlayer.src = videoMP4;

If you want to specify multiple (typed) sources you need to create DOM elements as children of myPlayer.